# sql hibernate hql

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

How can we use regexp in sql query to fetch data(key/value) from a json field.
For more understanding i have a table market inside that book is json having a field as title .

```
{

        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": ["A123"],
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": ["A1235"],
                "price": 12.99
            }]
```

The query i have written is :

```
select * from market where books REGEXP('"title":\s*(\["[A-Za-z0-9]*"\])');
```

But I do not get output.

Comment: what data base are you using , your question is not clear , do you want to read the data from DB columns whicis stored in JSON form , if so - then every specific database have JSON functions already implemented  you can refer.

Comment: For example - oracel https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6287   , Mysql  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html   and IBM DB2 - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/json/src/tpc/db2z_jsonfunctions.html

Comment: this data is there in database already. I am using mySql 5.7.15 and i want to execute the select statement from table market in which books is a filed which stores json object  and title is property in that. Now i already have a title value and want to select all those records for which the title value is same as given

Comment: Please don't expect the exact solution to your problems on the stackover flow like that,  but with this portal you will always be guided in correct way , you can check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

there you go - follow the url

[MY_Sql_5.7_JSON_FUNCTIONS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)

JSON_EXTRACT - is the method - what you need -

JSON_EXTRACT(json_doc, path[, path] ...) -  is the syntax for it.

On the page you will find the examples also. Check it out.